# Unable to register the DLL/OCX: RegSvr32 failed with exit code 0xC0000005 with Inno Setup 5.2.3

Tags: inno-setup, privileges, regsvr32

I am trying to register a COM DLL using Inno Setup in a setup package I created.  During test installations on Vista, I get this error:

> Unable to register the DLL/OCX: RegSvr32 failed with exit code 0xC0000005

I click "Ignore" and my application appears to install, but I have to then open a command prompt (as an administrator) and then regsvr32 to install the COM DLL.  Is there any way to do this automatically in Inno Setup?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use self-registration (i.e. `regsvr32`), Microsoft provides more information on the reasons why in the [Windows Installer documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371608(VS.85).aspx)

Most commonly, certain dependencies that your application is looking for are not yet present (i.e. Microsoft DLLs deployed with your app) when the self-registration process happens.

Can InnoSetup write registry entries? That's all that `regsvr32` is accomplishing... you can use the WiX tool heat to extract the relevant registry information that `regsvr32` would put in place and then hand-port that back to InnoSetup code.

Comment: Are you sure about this? Inno Setup can't really use anything but `regsvr32` to install a DLL or OCX, any Windows Installer features don't really help here IMO.

Comment: Can't InnoSetup write registry entries? That's all that `regsvr32` is accomplishing... you can use the WiX tool `heat` to extract the relevant registry information that `regsvr32` would put in place and then hand-port that back to InnoSetup code.

Comment: That's interesting information; put that into your answer and I'll vote it up. Inno Setup surely can write to the registry. But I don't think that it will affect the problem the OP has, which looks more like a permission issue, in which case writing to the registry would probably fail as well.

Answer (score 1):

0xC0000005 = EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

The DLL is doing something that is causing regsvr32 to crash.